# How to wrap badge around component without lowering its own width?

Tags: html, css, vuetify.js

When wrapping some components inside a badge they loose their original width

```
<v-badge color="warning" icon="mdi-lock">
  <v-text-field label="lost width due to badge" />  
</v-badge>
```

which results into this ( [reproduction link](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNp9UMtuwjAQ/BXLZxKrrwuiFf0OzCHEC7j4JXsDrRD/3rUT0RBEb57Z8czurM78M4T62AGf8wWCDaZB+JCOscWxakIozwJso92ACm69Q6IgXslCI3xjtdVgFDPNBsy75CetcM90YluSS84E/bj5s2nUDljrjY9Z3kSn3Y6EmjKIsEpXxrcHyUdRj8KMT8j6RNUBQ8+Ke4llbBQrhty/m4iZHpW56+EZ9JUsxLUqPuPaBh+RdKH+St5Rk+csl8MgST5nhckcVZ2x5HvEkOZCdC4cdnXrrVjSTMTOobZQKW+XL/Vz/fomlE445mtIttpEf0oQKVHy2cgc9fbnUcAwJt+n+qW3HahseWclyP8IsYrgFESI/+490d7sPpnd7Z8zL9JdqEuj3SFNamxTqXC1zpLLjPfWJC538PUvSe7jvQ==) )

[image]

I know that the textfield component provides an `append` slot

```
<v-text-field label="field goes here">
  <template v-slot:append>
    <v-avatar color="warning" size="small">
      <v-icon icon="mdi-lock" />
    </v-avatar>
  </template>
</v-text-field>
```

but this is not the same ( [reproduction link](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNp9UVtuwjAQvIrlbxKrpf2JaEXPgfkwyQIufsk2oS3i7l0npiRBRZGi7OzszGZ2daYfzpXtEWhFFxG0UyLCOzeELNpCONd9doUW0mDFY3qwrq2JCIHPlEyL8BWLrQTVECU2oN447audhUD24IHTwQTOXF1JWwRlY4WuYJoRp9+mFVF4UltlPaqehDfS7DglQf4AAkELpSbieVTisiS9kKYbWShbH3CQTU3Y1WW8IRsFc+Pe/vWvkeBpMgnL6WWPLteBLJ1RqZ31EXmu/AzW4DnOic5zI3BakQ5JGN4r1ZzuY3ShYuxo3GFX1lazJfaYP5ooNRSN1ct5+Vy+vLJGhjjESwi62Hh7CuDRkdPZQDzK7fd/BrmNuk/lvJfNUJK8k2Ko34IvPN4Uj+8f7j3hjnaf9O72T54Xbi6YpZLmECYx1qGLcLVOlMuM9tJI7v6Drn8Be6/2pw==) )

[image]

Is there a way to use the badge but don't affect actual widths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `width: 100%` to the badge tag like below:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <v-text-field label="width is fine" />
        <v-badge style="width: 100%" color="warning" icon="mdi-lock">
          <v-text-field label="lost width due to badge" />  
        </v-badge>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply but this is not the same as with using a badge as a wrapper. And then I would prefer using the avatar instead

Comment: @baitendbidz I edited the answer. Did you mean this?

Comment: Yes, but the class `w-100` is even better :)